# How to create a macro to transfer data from another spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, data-transfer

I need a macro that would copy all columns and rows from one workbook to another. I would like that macro to be triggered from a push of a button. When pressed, it would automatically transfer all the data. How can I accomplish this via a macro or code?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. What have you tried or researched so far in order to accomplish this? Also, what version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The image may explain one way to clone Workbook1.xlsx to Workbook2.xlsx in response to a click of a button in a different file:

[image: SU532608 example]